# Google Map custom Marker is added only once

Tags: android, google-maps, view, marker, geofire

i am trying to create custom marker for my app where i am trying to show only those users which are from a particular category. so i used a query and filtered the data. but when i try to mark them on google map and called the method that return bitmap for my customView it is returning only one bitmap and only one marker is displayed on the google map.rest of them are invisible

below is what i tried

```
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        UIDLocation.put(key,location);
       // mMap.addMarker(new 
    MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("Start"));
         marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
    LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)).title(key));
        markers.put(key, marker);

    }



   View child;
   //MarkeringMap is called when someone click on card which contains the 
   category names
   public void MarkeringMap(String string){ 
   child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.category_tags_items, null);
   Query query = 
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("WorkMen")
  .orderByChild("subcategory").startAt(string).endAt(string + 
  "\uf8ff").limitToLast(50);
  query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"there is 
  something",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }  
            for (DataSnapshot usersnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {               
                Users users = usersnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                usersLists.add(users);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),users.getName()+"this is 
     username ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               String keystring =  usersnapshot.getKey();
                for (Map.Entry<String,GeoLocation> entry : 
    UIDLocation.entrySet())
                {
                    Marker marker = markers.get(entry.getKey());
                    if (marker != null) {
                        marker.setVisible(false);                          
                                }   
                               if (keystring.equals(entry.getKey())){
                                   Users user1 = 
       usersnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                                   String s = user1.getName();
                                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),s+"this is 
       name  of key",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                   Bitmap b = getMarkerImage(child,s);
                                   Marker marker1 = 
      markers.get(entry.getKey());
                                   if (marker1 != null) {
                                       marker1.setVisible(true);
  //marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource 
// (R.drawable.locationmarker));

   marker1.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(b));                                
                                   }                                      
                    }
                }                  
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
   }





  public Bitmap getMarkerImage(View view,String  name){
    TextView textView1 = 
    (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tag_Category_name);
       textView1.setText(name);
       Drawable myDrawable = 
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_avatar);
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, 
    View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), 
   view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    Drawable drawable = view.getBackground();
    if (drawable != null)
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;

}
```

Comment: in this code where you set marker1 in google map ?

Comment: @JayThummar at addGeoQueryEventListener, in the keyEnteredMethod please check the updated code above

Comment: try to set marker in map inside MarkeringMap method inside for loop

Comment: @JayThummar its not working, what i am doing is initially i am showing all the markers on the map that's why i am using Geoquery outside MarkeringMap  method, MarkeringMap method is called only when someone clicks on the card view and it initially make all the markers invisible and later check for only those Id which is returned by geo query and makes them visible.

Comment: in listener method you  have declare marker  out side the method and initialize every time the listener called so maker object is always the latest marker you have created .  so create new marker inside the addGeoQueryEventListener  and add it in to google map

Comment: @JayThummar can you please help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592252/view-setparams-not-working-properly-in-firebase-recycler-view