# set Height of View Holder in OnBindViewHolder of Firebase Recycler

Tags: android, firebase, view, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerview` in which I want to check for a condition first and then show the item in the recycler view. So I tried setting the `View.visibility(gone)` but it is leaving blank spaces and the values are coming out fine. But then I tried setting up the params for height in view which is turned out to be a disaster and now nothing is coming up on my screen.

Below is what i have done

In my `onCreateView` I call a fragment Place Autocomplete

```
      autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener
      (new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
           
            myPosition = null;
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),place.getAddress(),
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          

            Double latitude1 = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            Double longitude1 =place.getLatLng().longitude;
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude1,longitude1);
            myPosition = latLng;
           
            filterResults(myPosition); //this i s for geoquery



        }

 private Map<String, GeoLocation> UIDLocation = new HashMap<>();
 public void filterResults(LatLng latLng){


    DatabaseReference ref = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Location");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new 
    GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), 2);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            UIDLocation.put(key,location);
        }
       // further methods of geoquery event listenere i havent changed 
      anything in them -----
     ------ public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
   filterlocation();  // this method call the firebase adapter 
    }


    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;
    public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void show(){
        mView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mView.setLayoutParams(new 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    public void hide(){
        mView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0,0));
    }
    /*
    public void setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams)
    {
      mView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
    */
    TextView userNameView;
    public void setDisplayName(String name)
    {
        userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.search_name);
        userNameView.setText(name);
    }
    TextView userCategory;
    public void setUserCategory(String name)
    {
        userCategory = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.search_category);
        userCategory.setText(name);
    }
    TextView userLocation;
    public void setUserLocation(String name)
    {
        userLocation = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.search_location);
        userLocation.setText(name);
    }
    TextView userStatusView;
    public void setUserStatus(String status)
    {
         userStatusView = (TextView) 
         mView.findViewById(R.id.search_category);
         userStatusView.setText(status);
    }
    public void setTypeFace(Typeface t){
        userNameView.setTypeface(t);
    }
 }
```

My `OnBinViewHolder` method is

```
         protected void onBindViewHolder(final UsersViewHolder holder, int 
         position, final Users model) {
            GeoLocation g = UIDLocation.get(model.getLocationID());
               if (g != null)
            {
                holder.show();
              holder.setLayoutParams();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "added", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("added", "onBindViewHolder: ");
            }
            else{
                holder.hide();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not Addded", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("not added", "onBindViewHolder: ");

                holder.setLayoutParamszero();
            }

            holder.setDisplayName(model.getName());
            String image = model.getThumb_image();
            holder.setUserImage(image, getContext());
            holder.setTypeFace(typeface);
            holder.setUserCategory(model.getSubcategory());
            holder.setUserLocation(model.getLocation());


            holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(), model.getName(), 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
```

my layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/search_result_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground">
          <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/search_name"
                android:layout_below="@+id/user_single_online_icon"

                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="Location" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_single_online_icon"
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search_name"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/search_name"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/online_icon" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_user_single_image"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/nextbtn1"

                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_navigate_next_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/search_user_single_image"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/search_user_single_image"
                android:text="Display Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/search_name"
                android:layout_below="@+id/search_name"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="Category" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

`view.hide()` is working fine without the params and showing values but the values are totally gone in every condition when I apply the params on View

Comment: Can you pls provide screenshots for each of the cases you tested so we know what exactly the problem is

Comment: @TamHuynh the problem when i set the layout every single item is gone in each case. My recycler view is empty in each case.i have also added my layout file in question

Comment: i changed my code and added a card layout in it and using cardView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  works fine for me but now there is another problem now its showing small gaps between items. like if it is hiding one element the gap is small and if it is hiding 3 or 4 item than the gap is quite bigger. there are no margins set for any layout.

Comment: Try using `app:contentPadding="0dp"` for the `CardView` to see if the gap is gone

Comment: i dont get it suddenly it stopped working for me a while ago it was working fine now all the elements are gone again and i just re started my android studio

Comment: @TamHuynh i tried adding a toast in my condtions after setting layouts only one toast is popping up thats " not added "

Comment: So you say `onBindViewHolder` is only called 1 time? Pls post your whole adapter code so we can investigate further.

Comment: @TamHuynh i have updated the code above please check

Comment: @TamHuynh i think my UIDLocation map is somehow gving null value

Comment: Did you debug it, put a breakpoint and see its actual value

Comment: yes it is giving a null value, i tried toast inside bindview and its showing null.@TamHuynh now its again showing values on second time selecting a place . i think its the first time my UIDLocation is not initialised when i call it but second time it is giving me values fine. what to do i want UIDlocation to have values before calling my adapter.

Comment: i want my  filterResults(myPosition); to fill up UIDlocation before calling filterlocation()  i tried putting filterlocation in  on place selected but that too is giving me null value

Comment: Sorry but your problem now is out of the scope of this question. I think you should debug your logic carefully, I cannot help you any further because the problem may come from deep inside you logic in other places.

Comment: @TamHuynh its ok i am still trying but app:contentPadding="0dp" is also not working , the gap is also still there is there anything else that i can do to change that. i think its because of parent layouot of my card view i.e. relative layout even when i have set the height to 0 its still taking some space.

Comment: You can use Tools > Layout Inspector or integrate `facebook Stetho` to inspect the layout and see where is the gap coming from